# jQuery columnizer not showing content in new div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to split my content into many divs with jQuery Columnizer. When I add `<p>` tags in my content the columnizer splits them and shows in new divs correctly.

However when I try to enter text without `<p>` tags the content splits but doesn't show in a new div. The new div is empty and content is split in the first div.

I have tried to find the solution but couldn't. I am using this code which works fine with `<p>` tags in the text.

**HTML**

```
<section class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
                                This commitment to Safety is backed up by a program of inspections, audits, communication and training which produces a safe workplace for our teams where they can thrive.

                                Our clean, well-organised workshops, structured processes and well - trained team members ensure the safety of the team, the safety of the repair for the Customer and other drivers on the road.

                                Our lifetime repair guarantee shows our commitment to putting our Customers back in their vehicle with a quality repair and a vehicle that is safe to be on the road.
</section>
```

**jquery:**

```
jQuery('.entry-content').columnize({
  columns: 2
});
```

Comment: Pls show us ur html code

Comment: Please add the HTML to the question, as it's relevant in order to recreate the problem

Comment: Can you include the details of *which* `columnizer` you're using?  Quick google showed multiple.

Comment: jquery.columnizer version 1.6.0

Comment: when i enter <p> tag then content split correctly.